# Does there exist the inverse of $XX^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm quite new in Linear Algebra and I read the question on a book, try to know how to solve that: Let $X$ be a matrix 5 by 3. Does there exist the inverse of $XX^T$?

Comment: Note that $XX^T$ is a square matrix (specifically 5 by 5 in this case), however there is no guarantee that it is invertible. Consider $X$ with all entries zero.

Comment: It's useful to know that if $A$ is a real $m \times n$ matrix then $A$ and $A^T A$ have the same null space. Proof: $Ax = 0 \implies A^T A x = 0.$ Conversely, $A^T Ax = 0 \implies x^T A^T Ax = 0 \implies \| Ax \|^2 = 0 \implies Ax = 0$.

Comment: $X^T$ is $3 \times 5$, so the dimension of its image is at most $3$, hence the dimension of its null space is at least $5-3 = 2$. Thus the dimension of the null space of $XX^T$ is also at least $2$, and in particular is not $0$, so $XX^T$ cannot be invertible.

Answer (score 4):

There does not. The rank goes smaller under matrix multiplication. Since $X$ has size $5\times 3$, $r(X)\leq3$, where $r$ denotes the rank. Hence $r(XX^T)\leq r(X)\leq3$. But $XX^T$ is invertible $\iff$ it has rank $5$. Hence it is not invertible.

Comment: Can you explain why $XX^T$ is invertible if it has rank 5?

Comment: @ChuongHuynh See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350991/n-by-n-invertible-matrix-a-has-textranka-n

Comment: @ChuongHuynh I think there are more than one way to prove it, and any textbook should have a proof of this. Since I don't know what you have already learned I'd suggest you to first find it in your textbook or check out this link shared by Hendrix.