# $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)\text{(invertible)}\iff rank(A)=n$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So, I find myself choosing to prove that a matrix $A \in M_{n×n}(F)$ is invertible if and only if $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n$.

My thoughts are that I should incorporate the fact that such a matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $\det{A} \neq 0$, and use this to show the linear independence of the column space of $A$.

Comment: I mean, if there are two identical columns, then $\det{A}=0$, but does this also apply for $m>2$ identical columns?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21990/proof-square-matrix-has-maximal-rank-if-and-only-if-it-is-invertible

Comment: @BarisaBarukh Since $\det A = 0$ for two identical columns then it certainly holds that $\det A = 0$ for _more_ than two identical columns (just ignore all but $2$ if you will).

Comment: Fortunately, the title of your question is not what you found yourself choosing to prove. Use words instead of formulas.

Comment: There are many, many ways to prove this. Can you tell us more about what you know so far? Determinants are probably not the most natural way to do this.

Comment: Can it be shown that $\det{A}=0 \implies A$ has $m\geq 2$ identical columns? This would be helpful. Perhaps $n-$linear forms are required here instead.

Comment: The determinant is $0$ if and only if the columns are linearly dependent. There doesn't have to be any identical columns. For example, consider the matrix with first column all $1$s, second column all $2$s, so on... This is a very elementary result, there's really no need to involve $n$-linear forms.

Comment: @EuYu Prove it.

Comment: @BarisaBarukh Prove what?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\operatorname{rank}(A)=n\iff$ the columns of $A$ are linearly independent $\overset{\text{why ?}}\iff$ there are linear combinations of the columns of $A$ which give the vectors $$e_i=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots\\0\\1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I wonder . . . $\overset{\overset{\overset{\overset{upward}{upward}}{upward}}{upward}}{upward}$ or what about $a^{a^{a^a}}$ or $b_{b_{b_b}}$

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder how far I could go.

Comment: Oh, wow. It is the same font size after a while. Anyway . . .

Comment: It sort of defaults to a set font size after the second go.