# Linear Algebra Statements

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of these statements are true?

(I) If $A$ is a matrix of full rank, then $A$ is invertible.

(II) If $A$ can be expressed as a product of elementary matrices, then $A$ is of full rank.

(III) If $A$ is symmetric, then a basis for the row space of $A$ is also a basis for the column space of $A$.

Understanding that equivalent statements are only for $A_{n \times n}$ matrix, so (I) cannot be true. I have put (II) and (III) to be the correct statements, am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I) is, in fact, an "if and only if", so it's more than only true. You can find a proof here: [Proof - Square Matrix has maximal rank if and only if it is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21990/proof-square-matrix-has-maximal-rank-if-and-only-if-it-is-invertible)

(II) is also true. Note that $\text{det}(A\cdot B) = \text{det}A \cdot \text{det} B$. The determinant of a elementary matrix is never zero because they are invertible, so the product of determinants of the elementary matrices is not zero, implying that $\text{det}A \neq 0$, therefor invertible.

(III) holds trivially, but the reciprocal is not true.

As the statements are talking about invertibility and base span of a matrix you can assume that $A \in M_{n}$ (is a square matrix).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation. Do you mind explaining to me why III is false?

Comment: (III) is not false. I wrote "it holds trivially", which means it can be prooved very easily. I just said that the reciprocal is not true, which means that if the row space and the column space have the same base, then the matrix $A$ doesn't have to be symmetric.

Comment: I see, sorry for the misunderstanding as English is not my 1st language. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Don't worry! Hope I could help